# How to convert datatype in Method argument from Struct?

Tags: c#, methods, struct, enums, type-conversion

## the problem

I made a **struct**, an **enum**, and a **method**.
The enum is used in the struct. The method uses the struct.

When I try to accept the *input from the user* in the main, and **call the method**, I get a conversion error. *I cannot convert from a struct to a double.*

How do I convert the input from the user in this case?

#### extra info

(This is supposed to convert temperature types, right now I only wrote the conversion for 1 of the temperatures, but it's the same for the others (except the formulas))

PS: I haven't learned about lists and interfaces and I cannot do this in a different class.

```
public enum MyEnum {C,F,K}

public struct MyStruct
{
    public double foo;
    public MyEnum bar; 
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Make user put in a double followed by a space and one of the Enums");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] parts = input.Split(' '); 

        MyStruct temp = new MyStruct (); 
        temp.foo= double.Parse(parts[0]);

        if(parts[1] == "C")
        {

            TheMethodIUSedForC(parts[0]);
            temp.bar= MyEnum.C;
        }
    }
    public MyStruct TheMethodIUSedForC(MyStruct t)
    {
        if (t.bar== MyEnum.F)
        {
            t.bar= MyEnum.F;
            t.foo = (t.foo* 1.8) + 32;
            return t;
        }
        else if (t.bar== MyEnum.K)
        {
            t.bar= MyEnum.K;
            t.foo= t.foo + 273.15;
            return t;
        }
        else
        {
            return t;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question properly, but you can build your temporary struct and pass it to the method like this:

```
public enum MyEnum {C,F,K}

public struct MyStruct
{
    public double foo;
    public MyEnum bar;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Make user put in a double followed by a space and one of the Enums");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] parts = input.Split(' ');

        MyStruct temp = new MyStruct();
        temp.foo = double.Parse(parts[0]);
        temp.bar = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum),parts[1]);
        MyMethod(temp);
    }
    public static MyStruct MyMethod(MyStruct t)
    {
        if (t.bar == MyEnum.F)
        {
            t.bar = MyEnum.F;
            t.foo = (t.foo * 1.8) + 32;
            return t;
        }
        else if (t.bar == MyEnum.K)
        {
            t.bar = MyEnum.K;
            t.foo = t.foo + 273.15;
            return t;
        }
        else
        {
            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

In this way you don't even need to reassign the "bar" variable inside the "MyMethod", you can just elaborate the foo variable.

And of course you need to handle properly the case the provided letter cannot be parsed as MyEnum. For this purpose you can use Enum.TryParse(...)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code an trying to compile it I cannot get error you got. In my case error is not about **double** but **string** which is correct because **parts[0]** is string.
Your method:

```
public MyStruct TheMethodIUSedForC(MyStruct t)
```

accepts **MyStruct** as parameter, so you cannot pass **parts[0]** as parameter because it's of string type. It will compile if you pass eg. **temp** which is of MyStruct type. However it will probably not work as intended because **bar** field isn't yet set.
Change:

```
if(parts[1] == "C")
{
    TheMethodIUSedForC(parts[0]);
    temp.bar= MyEnum.C;
}
```

to:

```
if(parts[1] == "C")
{
    temp.bar= MyEnum.C;
    TheMethodIUSedForC(temp);
}
```

and it should be better.